# Compress & Upload large videos to Google cloud storage using Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

There are a couple of notable packages on pub.dev that offer video compression. I've tried them, and other sketchy packages, and none work well once a video gets around 300MB. They crash or have other issues on various platforms and hardware. Namely, [video compress and light compressor](https://pub.dev/packages?q=video%20compress). The GH commits and support are concerning as well on the packages I've seen for video compression in pub.dev. PR's not being pulled in and issues not being resolved in a timely manner and some quite serious for recent android APK updates. So not something I want in my dependency stack.

I am uploading to Google Cloud Storage using FlutterFire. While my code does upload using [FireBaseStorage upload task](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#handling-tasks) it does not have any ability to compress on the client side or handle background uploading when the app is closed.

So, currently on the server side, I have a GCF that triggers on file uploaded. Then I use nodejs ffmpeg, which is baked into GCF's to compress server side and convert to H264. And finally delete the original large upload video and save the compressed video to storage.

This solution works, but depending on a user's connection and whether they are on wifi, can take an awful long time and when it fails or the user closes the app, my current solution is useless.

I wish there was a solid native library on Android and iOS, that I could tap into, to confidently perform compression and conversion from any format to H264 and also allow uploading, whether my app is closed or in the background, to GC storage. Any thoughts? I wish this was standard in FlutterFire's cloud storage handling!

I have yet to test [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg), but only because some have said it runs so slowly on client. So again, [Flutter/Dart can access natively written code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels), but I don't know where to start on Android/iOS to do this the right way. And I understand this is what some of the packages are doing, but they do not work with large videos, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on Android and iOS.

**My code for handling upload tasks to GC storage.**

```dart
 
 ​  ​Future<​void​>​ ​uploadTask​({ 
 ​    ​required​ ​WidgetRef​ ref, 
 ​    ​required​ ​File​ file, 
 ​    ​required​ ​String​ objectPath, 
 ​    ​SettableMetadata​?​ metaData, 
 ​    ​bool​ deleteAfterUpload ​=​ ​false​, 
 ​    ​bool​ displayProgressNotification ​=​ ​false​, 
 ​  }) ​async​ { 
 ​    ​String​ filePath ​=​ file.path; 
 ​    filename ​=​ ​basename​(file.path); 
  
 ​    ​/// Remove any instances of '//' from the path. 
 ​    ​final​ ​String​ path ​=​ ​'$​storagePath​/$​objectPath​'​.​replaceAll​(​'//'​, ​'/'​); 
 ​    ​UploadTask​ task ​=​ storage.​ref​(path).​putFile​( 
 ​          ​File​(filePath), 
 ​          metaData, 
 ​        ); 
  
 ​    ​/// Store UploadTask in StateNotifierProvider to monitor progress. 
 ​    ref.​read​(uploadingStateProvider.notifier).​myUploadTask​(task); 
 ​  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did resolve, to some degree, my original post's questions and frustrations by using the [ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl) package on the client side, and then ffmpeg again in GCF on the server side. In summary:

- Within 60 seconds, I can now compress a 2 minute video by 90% before uploading to firebase storage.
- Using `onFinalize` via GCF on the server side I run ffmpeg again on the uploaded video and gain another 77% reduction in file size on the server side without any loss in video quality.
- My solution does not yet upload while the app is closed.
- On the client side, this solution requires setting the camera `ResolutionPreset` to `high` (720p), rather than `max`, which can be a minimum of 1080p, and setting the ffmpeg `-preset veryfast` rather than the `medium` default.

**Camera & ffmpeg solution settings:**

- [Flutter camera package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) `ResolutionPreset` to `high`
- ffmpeg `-preset veryfast`

**Transcoding results stats for 2 minute video:**

- Before transcode: 255MB
- After client side transcode: 25MB (90% decrease in size before upload)
- Time to transcode: 60 seconds
- `onFinalized` GCF ffmpeg transcode: 19MB (77% reduction in size)
- In total a 93% reduction in size while keep high quality 720p video.

[flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) is archived, the new ffmpeg flutter package is [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter).

That being said, I used [ffmpeg_kit_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) to build my solution on the client side, rather than the server side, and transcode the video before uploading.

**Cons**:

1. Doubled my app size to use ffmpeg, because I needed access to both `lame` and `x264` so I had to install the full-gpl package to gain access to these libraries.
2. A two minute video can take up to 60 seconds to transcode.

**The pros**:

1. Low bandwidth connections will operate much better after a video is reduced in size by 90%.
2. Large videos will transcode and ffmpegkit does not crash like other flutter packages I've tried.
3. The second pass with ffmpeg on GCF gains another 77% reduction in size taking a video of 100's of MB's down to just 10-20 MB max for eventually delivery.
4. Costs lower on the front and back end.

So, you'll have to decide if the pros outweighs the cons and if 720p is high enough quality for playback. For me 720p looks perfect for video playback on a mobile phone and 1080p or higher was big time overkill.

I've provided sample code (not full classes) to give anyone looking to implement my solution a try. It became very important, due to the amount of time to transcode, to display a progress meter so the user does not give up on the process. You'll see my simple solution to displaying transcoding progress.

**pubspec.yaml**

- [camera package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) for video recording
- [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) required for statenotifier and transcode/upload progress notifications
- [ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) ([the full_gpl gets the ffmpeg package with most libraries](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit#8-packages)) required to get `h264` and `libmp3lame` encoders to produce most widely playable transcoded videos.
- [wakelock](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock) required because transcoding takes so long you don't want the phone to sleep while transcoding.

```yaml
dependencies:
  camera: ^0.9.4+12
  flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.3
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full_gpl: ^4.5.1
  wakelock: ^0.5.6
```

**Riverpod `StateNotifier`** classes to send progress updates to the ui for both transcoding and uploading to firebase storage. Assumption that users are familiar with Riverpod and StateNotifiers.

```dart
@immutable
class TranscodeUploadMessage {
  const TranscodeUploadMessage({
    required this.id,
    required this.statusTitle,
    required this.statusMessage,
    required this.uploadPercentage,
    required this.isRunning,
    required this.completed,
    required this.showSpinner,
    required this.showPercentage,
    required this.showError,
  });

  final int id;
  final String statusTitle;
  final String statusMessage;
  final String uploadPercentage;
  final bool isRunning;
  final bool completed;
  final bool showSpinner;
  final bool showPercentage;
  final bool showError;

  TranscodeUploadMessage copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? statusTitle,
    String? statusMessage,
    String? uploadPercentage,
    bool? isRunning,
    bool? completed,
    bool? showSpinner,
    bool? showPercentage,
    bool? showError,
  }) {
    return TranscodeUploadMessage(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      statusTitle: statusTitle ?? this.statusTitle,
      statusMessage: statusMessage ?? this.statusMessage,
      uploadPercentage: uploadPercentage ?? this.uploadPercentage,
      isRunning: isRunning ?? this.isRunning,
      completed: completed ?? this.completed,
      showSpinner: showSpinner ?? this.showSpinner,
      showPercentage: showSpinner ?? this.showPercentage,
      showError: showError ?? this.showError,
    );
  }
}

class TranscodeUploadMessageNotifier
    extends StateNotifier<List<TranscodeUploadMessage>> {
  TranscodeUploadMessageNotifier() : super([]);

  /// Since our state is immutable, we are not allowed to do
  /// `state.add(message)`. Instead, we should create a new list of messages which
  /// contains the previous items and the new one.
  ///
  /// Using Dart's spread operator here is helpful!
  void set(TranscodeUploadMessage message) {
    state = [...state, message];
  }

  /// Our state is immutable. So we're making a new list instead of changing
  /// the existing list.
  void remove(int id) {
    state = [
      for (final message in state)
        if (message.id != id) message,
    ];
  }

  /// Update message. Since our state is immutable, we need to make a copy of
  /// the message. We're using our `copyWith` method implemented before to help
  /// with that.
  void update(TranscodeUploadMessage messageUpdated) {
    state = [
      for (final message in state)
        if (message.id == messageUpdated.id)

          /// Use copyWith to update a message
          message.copyWith(
            statusTitle: messageUpdated.statusTitle,
            statusMessage: messageUpdated.statusMessage,
            uploadPercentage: messageUpdated.uploadPercentage,
            isRunning: messageUpdated.isRunning,
            completed: messageUpdated.completed,
            showSpinner: messageUpdated.showSpinner,
            showPercentage: messageUpdated.showPercentage,
            showError: messageUpdated.showError,
          )
        else

          /// other messages, which there are not any at this time, are not
          /// modified
          message,
    ];
  }
}

/// Using StateNotifierProvider to allow the UI to interact with our
/// TranscodeUploadMessageNotifier class.
final transcodeMessageProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<
    TranscodeUploadMessageNotifier, List<TranscodeUploadMessage>>((ref) {
  return TranscodeUploadMessageNotifier();
});
```

**ffmpegkit package running ffmpeg commands** and sending transcoding statistics to the StateNotifier. (Missing quite a bit of code, but pseudocode to demonstrate.)

```dart
/// By default, set to video ffmpeg command.
String ffmpegCommand = '-i $messageUri '
    '-acodec aac '
    '-vcodec libx264 '
    '-f mp4 -preset veryfast '
    '-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov '
    '-crf 23 $newMessageUri';

if (_recordingType == RecordingType.audio) {
  ffmpegCommand = '-vn '
      '-i $messageUri '
      '-y '
      '-acodec libmp3lame '
      '-f '
      'mp3 '
      '$newMessageUri';
}

/// Set the initial state notifier as we start transcoding.
ref
.read(transcodeMessageProvider.notifier)
.set(const TranscodeUploadMessage(
  id: 1,
  statusTitle: 'Transcoding Recording',
  statusMessage: 'Your recording is being transcoded '
      'before upload. Please do not navigate away from this screen.',
  uploadPercentage: '0%',
  isRunning: true,
  completed: false,
  showSpinner: false,
  showPercentage: false,
  showError: false,
));

await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
  ffmpegCommand,
  (Session session) async {
    final ReturnCode? returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

    if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
      /// Transcoding is complete, now display uploading message
      /// and spinner at 0%.
      ref
          .read(transcodeMessageProvider.notifier)
          .update(const TranscodeUploadMessage(
            id: 1,
            statusTitle: 'Uploading Recording',
            statusMessage:
                'Your recording is now being '
                'uploaded. Please do not navigate away from this screen.',
            uploadPercentage: '0%',
            isRunning: true,
            completed: false,
            showSpinner: true,
            showPercentage: true,
            showError: false,
          ));

      /// Upload the now transcoded video/audio to cloud storage where
      /// Use flutterfire firebase storage tasks to get upload
      /// progress. Your firebase storage function can also 
      /// reuse the transcodeMessageProvider to send UI state
      /// updates for the upload, which will happen very quickly
      /// even on slow connections now that the recording size
      /// is dramatically reduced.
      await uploadRecordingToFirebaseCloudStorage(ref);
    } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
      // Do something if canceled
    } else {
      // Do something with the error
    }
  },
  (Log log) => debugPrint(log.getMessage()),
  (Statistics statistic) {
    /// Statistics provides a running transcoding progress meter.
    int completePercentage = (statistic.getTime() * 100) ~/ _duration!;
    ref
        .read(transcodeMessageProvider.notifier)
        .update(TranscodeUploadMessage(
          id: 1,
          statusTitle: 'Transcoding Recording',
          statusMessage: 'Your recording is being '
              'transcoded. Please do not navigate away from this screen.',
          uploadPercentage: '$completePercentage%',
          isRunning: true,
          completed: false,
          showSpinner: true,
          showPercentage: true,
          showError: false,
        ));
  }).then((Session session) {
debugPrint(
    'Async FFmpeg process started with sessionId ${session.getSessionId()}.');
}).catchError((error) async {
debugPrint('transcoding error: $error');
});
```

**Use a Riverpod Consumer to update UI** by watching the StateNotifier and displaying updated state in your UI.

```dart
Consumer(
    builder: (context, watch, child) {
      final List<TranscodeUploadMessage> messages =
          ref.watch(transcodeMessageProvider);
      if (messages.isEmpty) {
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      }

      final message = messages[0];

      if (message.isRunning ||
          message.completed ||
          message.showError) {
        // Display widgets with StateNotifier data
      }

      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    },
)
```